# Typescript expand type based on array as generic parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to pass array of special keywords to a type and based on those keywords the type should expand

```
type Keywords = 'totals' | 'body'  // ...and more

type Model<K extends Keywords[] = []> = {
  id: number
} 
& (K extends 'totals'[] ? {total: number, amount: number}: {})
& (K extends 'body'[] ? {body: string, name: string}: {})

const m: Model<['totals', 'body']> = {id: 1}   // Main problem here: Only id exist
```

I am not sure how to check if `'totals'` in `K`. In the above example both conditions should be valid, as `'totals'` and `'body'` are passed to the generic array. But seems like they both are invalid.

secondary problem (not that important, but good to be resolved):

```
const words: Keywords[] = ['totals']
```

I want to secure that `words` has the correct type, but it gets all the possible `Keywords`, not only what is assigned to it. The goal is to use it like this:

```
type NewModel = Model<typeof words>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `K extends "totals"[]`, swap it around and check the element type instead of the array type: `"totals" extends K[number]`. It's tricky to think about sometimes with unions, but remember that when you extend a union, you *reduce* the number of members of the union; `"totals"` is a subtype of `"totals" | "body"`, but `"totals" | "body"` is not a subtype of `"totals"`.

If you do those two things, it works:

```
type Keywords = "totals" | "body"; // ...and more

type Model<K extends Keywords[] = []> = {
    id: number;
}
& ("totals" extends K[number] ? { total: number; amount: number } : {})
& ("body" extends K[number] ? { body: string; name: string } : {});

const m: Model<["totals", "body"]> = { id: 1 }; // Missing properties error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHcD2AnAJgZygXigImCWAEMAbDPKAH3wCMk0Q8BuKAejagDofiA7NFAC2qCACgxoSFACyDCKQA8MKBAAewCAKxxEqTAG0AujijGAfKYDeYqHagBLNAC4ofAK5DaEFMzEBfMQAyKAAKAiIyClUNLUxYAw8vHxMAfigrKEISUlck718oYhF3PmA8zwKofyhXK38ASmCwvHpGSnVNbQT8lKh0zLaQVwxgFAc+AHNWPmKIEbGJyerajMa-MQBjJD5R4Vc5NAVFAwicigAaOgYmI0tcTKdXAEZq1g5ZBwwMJagwFCQkBQwAcECwPgBKCKWCOPxQEDQQA)

> secondary problem (not that important, but good to be resolved):
>
> ```
> const words: Keywords[] = ['totals']
> ```

The type of `words` there is *just* `Keywords[]`, not specifically `"totals"[]`, so it's too wide-open. You could use `"totals"[]` but that's redundant, ideally we want TypeScript to infer that type for us. To do that, we have two options: `as const` or the newer `satisfies` (thanks for reminding me of that):

```
const words = ["totals"] as const;
// or
const words = ["totals"] satisfies Keywords[];
```

Both result in the type of `words` being `"totals"[]`, but `satisfies` gives us a better developer experience by warning us if we include elements in the array that aren't in `Keyword`, so that's probably what we want.

Since that creates a readonly type, you'll need to update your type parameter constraint on `Model` to `K extends readonly Keywords[]`:

```
type Keywords = "totals" | "body"; // ...and more

type Model<K extends readonly Keywords[] = []> = {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
    id: number;
}
& ("totals" extends K[number] ? { total: number; amount: number } : {})
& ("body" extends K[number] ? { body: string; name: string } : {});

const words = ["totals"] satisfies Keywords[];
//         ^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

const m2: Model<typeof words> = { id: 1 }; // Missing properties error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHcD2AnAJgZygXigImCWAEMAbDPKAH3wCMk0Q8BuKAejagDofiA7NFAC2qCACgxoSFACyDCKQA8MKBAAewCAKwoIxNEj6kQseMnQYA2gF0cUGwD47AbzEcogJCIv3n7+8A9QKDAsSgwqABLNAAuKD4AVyFaCBRmMQBfMQAyKAAKAiIyClUNLUxYSwSklNsAfihnKEISUliq5NSoYhF4vmA2xI6odKhY53SASmy8vHpGSnVNbQr2mqh6xrmQWIxgFAi+AHNWPm6IHb2Dw+HRhsm0sQBjQ12oc3LcSwKWilsMYmAEQwADMIhAsHBEKhMDY0u5wgioP5ESiwsF0Rj0RJnnxXkIAEyxORoBSKKQQJDAt7QjBOXCNKKxACMw1Y7hkQIwVygYBQSEgKEB4NUKD5KC6WBJXN0aDEQA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About the second problem I was thinking of using ```satisfies``` operator. Seems like it is created just for that kind of things. Guarantees a type safety and does not enforce the type

Comment: @OktayYuzcan - Good idea, that improves the developer experience by preventing us from including elements that aren't covered by `Keyword`. I'll update the answer to call that out.